# Finder crashing about once a minute: Segmentation Fault

Tags: finder, crash

I just had to send my MacBook Pro in for a logic board replacement. It seemed fine at first when I got it back, but now I realize that Finder is crashing about once a minute. From system.log:

```
May  1 09:27:27 CFArgument-2 com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[280] (com.apple.Finder[1790]): Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
May  1 09:27:27 CFArgument-2.local ReportCrash[1793]: Saved crash report for Finder[1790] version 10.9.2 (10.9.2) to /Users/adam/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2014-05-01-092727_CFArgument-2.crash
May  1 09:27:27 CFArgument-2.local ReportCrash[1793]: Removing excessive log: file:///Users/adam/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2014-05-01-090714_CFArgument-2.crash
```

And the [contents of that log file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/atuttle/0ef7e9082c9013553548/raw/c0309af1a86fe718a36b95dae8612a3756662dc9/gistfile1.txt).

I would really, really rather not have to take it back to the Apple Store for a fix. I've just spent the last 4 days without it at all and have lots of work to get done and of course I'm on a tight deadline.

Any ideas what could be causing this or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the Google Drive sync app was causing the problem. This was something that was enabled before sending my laptop in for repairs. Disabling it now, the crashes have stopped.

I don't know what's wrong with it and I haven't tried reinstalling it to fix it.